# Not able to bind the records using knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

By using the following article : http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=847,  I tried to develop the sample app. In order to keep things separate I tried to move the javascript code to a separate js file : **EmployeeInfo.js** and referenced the js file in the head section of the Create.cshtml as mentioned below:

```
<head>    
     <script src="~/Scripts/EmployeeInfo.js"></script>
</head>
```

But I am not able to display the existing records from the database. On debugging the code I found that the GetEmployees() method is invoked and data.length is also greater than 0 but the data is not able to bind with the table to display all the records. Any help on this is appreciated.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Employees">
                                <tr style="border: solid" data-bind="click: $root.getselectedemployee" id="updtr">
                                    <td><span data-bind="text: EmpNo"></span></td>
                                    <td><span data-bind="text: EmpName"></span></td>
                                    <td><span data-bind="text: Salary"></span></td>
                                    <td><span data-bind="text: DeptName"></span></td>
                                    <td><span data-bind="text: Designation"></span></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button data-bind="click: $root.deleterec">Delete</button></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
```

Can anyone help me to understand the problem.

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing working code, my only guess is that you're applyingBindings before the page has rendered.  Note Step 8's instructions:

> Step 8: Before closing body tag define the  block where the
>   ViewModel will be defined as below:

You've moved the code into a separate file, which is good, but you've moved it into the head tag.  DOM order of operations will load and execute this script before the `<body>` has had a chance to render, and so the ko.applyBindings binds to nothing.  You have two options.

Either move your script declaration to just before the closing body tag:

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/EmployeeInfo.js"></script>
</body>
```

Or, assuming you're using jQuery, wrap your script code in this file inside of the document ready function:

```
$(function (){
    // ... Your code ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your suggestion helped me a lot to understand the problem.